# Non-Greedy Regex Does Not Terminate

Tags: python, regex

My current regular expression is supposed to get the return value of a specific PHP function if it is a string.

My first regular expression worked, but I knew that it does not match all cases, so I wanted to expand on it.

Here is the first regex:

```
"public function getVersion\\(\\)\\s*?{\\s*.*return\\s*'(.+)';"
```

This works for:

```
public function getVersion() {
    return '1.0.0';
}
```

But not for cases with where there are lines between the function name and the return:

```
public function getVersion() {
    # SomeComment
    some_function()
    return '1.0.0';
}
```

Here is the overhauled version:

```
"public function getVersion\\(\\)\\s*?{(\\s|.)*?return\\s*'(.+)';"
```

I changed it to match any number of characters or newlines before the return, using (\s|.)*?

After implementing it, though, I found out that the search does not terminate now. I'm not sure why that's the case. Even if no result is found, shouldn't it terminate after reaching the end of the search text? Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Do not use `(\s|.)`, just use `re.S` so that a dot could match a newline. But I think that regex is not the proper way to parse code.

Comment: @stribizhev I'd like to parse the code without regex. What alternatives do exist? I haven't found a python library to parse PHP code yet, and writing one myself would take a lot of time.

Comment: I am no expert in code parsing, what I could find on the Web is [phply](https://github.com/ramen/phply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use re.DOTALL parameter for linebreaks. Consider this:

```
import re

text = '''public function getVersion() {
    # SomeComment
    some_function()
    return '1.0.0';
}'''

regex_comp = re.compile("public function getVersion\\(\\)\\s*?{\\s*.*return\\s*'(.+)';", re.DOTALL)

print regex_comp.search(text).group(1)
```